# jQuery Action After Loop, Related to Krams Spring jQuery File Upload

Tags: jquery, spring

I'm working with Kram's jQuery/Spring example:

http://krams915.blogspot.com/2012/06/file-upload-with-spring-and-jquery-part_20.html

I'm running into an issue in this function:

```
$('#upload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
            $("#addingResultsData").show();
            $('body').data('filelist').push(file);
            $('#filename').append(formatFileDisplay(file));
        });
        alert('hits on each file added');
    }
});
```

A "Please wait" image displays while the files are added, but when the addition of files is complete, the image still displays and never goes away - unless I click the "Upload" button, where everything clears as intended.

This is the div I need to turn off, after addition of files is complete:

```
<div id="addingResultsData" style="0 0 10px 0; text-align: center;">
    Adding files. Please wait. <br /><img src="/images/loading.gif" alt="Adding files." />
</div>
```

I cannot seem to get it working within the above function.  Any idea what I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem the "Please wait" is being shown but never hidden.  Adding `.hide()` at the end of the `done` function should give you the behaviour you want.

```
$('#upload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
            $("#addingResultsData").show();
            $('body').data('filelist').push(file);
            $('#filename').append(formatFileDisplay(file));
        });
        $("#addingResultsData").hide();
        alert('hits on each file added');
    }
});
```

Also, the code as you have it will only display the image after the upload is finished and while it is adding the results into the DOM.  If you'd like to display it at the start of the upload instead, you could do something like this:

```
var counter = 0;
$('#upload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    send: function (e, data) {
        counter++;
        $("#addingResultsData").show();
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
            $('body').data('filelist').push(file);
            $('#filename').append(formatFileDisplay(file));
        });
        counter--;
        if (0 === counter) $("#addingResultsData").hide();
        alert('hits on each file added');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The issue is that where I have the alert, that displays each time a file is added.  So for 5 files, the alert hits 5 times.  The hiding needs to occur outside the loop, or I need a check after the last addition, to then hide the div.

Comment: @user2429713 Ah yes I see what you mean. I updated the second example snippet to use a counter so the div will only hide after the last upload is complete.  The `progressall` callback may be a better choice though, I'm just not able to test when it fires at the moment.